# Cómo interceptar toda la salida de express en una aplicación nodejs

Tags: nodejs, express

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que usa módulos que ponen sus propios `middlewares` (por ejemplo [`passportjs`](http://passportjs.org/)).

Quisiera capturar toda la salida que se haga a través del objeto `res` del `express` para `loguearlo` o guardarlo. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();

// capture_all_res(app, 'guardar.txt')

app.listen(3000);

app.get('/uno',function(req,res){
    res.send('algo');
});

app.get('/dos',function(req,res){
    res.header('Content-Type','text/plain');
    res.end('otra cosa');
});
```

Me serviría tanto hacer un `pipe` o mandarlo a un archivo o a una función que capture cada salida.

Comment: Si lo que deseas es simplemente loggearlo en la consola usa morgan: https://github.com/expressjs/morgan , si no podrías construir tu propia función middleware que te guarde los logs en un archivo.

Comment: morgan es un `request` logger. Lo que necesito es un `response-logger`

Comment: Entiendo... pues simplemente loguea lo que necesites antes de utilizar `res.send, res.end, res.json,`...

Comment: Aunque quizás esto te es de utilidad : https://www.npmjs.com/package/on-finished

Answer (score 1):

Tan sencillo como hacer:

```
app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
  // hacer algo
  next();
});
```

Comment: Sí, hago eso para capturar la entrada (lo que viene por req), pero no entiendo cómo hacer para capturar la salida (lo que estoy enviando en `res.send`, `res.header`, `res.end`, etc)

Comment: Los middlewares reciben 3 parámetros: Request, Response y next. La salida siempre saldrá por el objeto Response. Por lo que, debes extraer la info que te interesa de él. Mírate el objeto [Response](http://expressjs.com/es/4x/api.html#res).

Comment: No sé cómo hacer eso. Por eso lo pregunto. Sé poner un middleware y capturar el objeto `req`, pero necesito un ejemplo de cómo capturar todas las salidas posibles que podrían hacerse con cualquiera de las funciones de `response`.

Comment: Creo que habría que evaluar la conveniencia de que eliminaras tu respuesta para que otros no crean que la pregunta ya está contestada y así tenga menos probabilidades de que aparezca una respuesta que conteste la pregunta que hice. Gracias